# SLL on a double word in SPARC?

Tags: sparc

Is there a way that I can do a left logical shift on a double word in SPARC assembly?

I have:

```
ldd [%fp - 8], %l0
```

to load the 64bit memory address. Note that this is not an integer, merely a sequence of bytes, so the left logical shift is not acting as a multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentals of Computer Organization and Design Page 988 (You can look it up on google books):

```
sllx Rs1,Rs2,Rd
```

Left shifts a 64 bit value `Rs1` by the 6 least significant bits of `Rs2` and stores it in `Rd`. Many of the instructions from Sparc v8 are postfixed with an `x` to denote the 64bit version of that instruction. For instance `sllx`, `srax`, `srlx`...

By the way, I just came across this document which seems much easier to get bits of info from that the Sparc v9 manual itself: https://openresearch-repository.anu.edu.au/bitstream/1885/40814/3/TR-CS-00-03.pdf